# android on login application to switch between two intents

Tags: android

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        txtUserName=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
        txtPassword=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
   error1:   next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

           public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddName.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
       }}
   error2:  )

       };

    if((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText().toString())){
           Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Login Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } else{
           Toast.makeText(LoginappActivity.this, "Invalid Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
           }
             }

    }
```

i have created a login application to change from one intent to another intent. The other .java works fine

- error1: Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead
- error2: Multiple markers at this line
          - `Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration`
          - `Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName`
          - `Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression`
          - `Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody`

Comment: Could you post lines 35 and 41, or a larger code snippet that contains them?

Comment: Please look over the code and fix the indentation and make a code box of the errors as well. Makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: line:35 next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be Like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

     txtUserName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtUname);
     txtPassword = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
    Button btnLogin = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if ((txtUserName.getText().toString()).equals(txtPassword.getText()
            .toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(DelActivity.this, "Login Successful",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(DelActivity.this, "Invalid Login",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
        }
    });

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddName.class);
            //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: while running this application it runs fine going to the 2 page  but its not showing whether the login is a succesful one or a invalid one please help me

Answer (score 3):

You have there some extra `}}` at the end of the `onClick` function. It should be:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {   

       public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddName.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); 
       }
});
```

By the way, I find the usage of the onClickListener inside another onClickListener very confusing. You should separate them.

Comment: i modified it but he same error continues Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression
 - Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete EnumDeclaration
 - Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete 
  EnumHeaderName